# How can I pass the pid of one shell to another shell created within the parent shell and check if the parent process is running or killed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a c++ file which I call using my shell script(monitoring.sh)

```
cfile="/home/workspace/printprocess/print"
cmp=start
if [ $1 = $cmp ]
  then
  $cfile
fi
```

This works fine when I run `./monitoring.sh start`

Now I want to create another shell within this shell to store its pid and the other shell should have the  pid of parent shell which is running.

It is something like this:

```
if [$1 = $cmp ]
then 
$cfile
cat > pid_no.sh <<EOF

while (process not killed)
echo $p >pid_no.sh
```

I'm new to Linux.Please help with the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ID's of shell processes (and their parents) can be derived directly using $$ or BASHPID, depending on the case, as well explained here:

[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62231/bashpid-and-differ-in-some-cases](http://The%20ID's%20of%20shell%20processes%20(and%20their%20parents)%20can%20be%20derived%20directly%20using%20$$%20or%20BASHPID,%20depending%20on%20the%20case,%20as%20well%20explained%20https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62231/bashpid-and-differ-in-some-cases)

There should be no need to create an additional script only to get the PID, if I understand your problem well.

Comment: I was asked to store the pid of the shell script in another shell script and I can't open the link for the site which you have mentioned

Comment: Does the c program return immediately (by forking itself into the background), or does is stay running. ? If it goes to the background, does it published the PID of the actual server somehow (e.g., stderr) ?

Comment: the c program keeps running continuously @dash-o

Comment: my problem is I have to save the pid in a different script file and monitor whether the process is still running or killed

Comment: @inihsrah The variable you referenced $$, BASHPID, capture the PID of bash processes. I believe OP asks for PID of the (c) program/server to be saved. This is achieved with '$!', after sending the program to the background

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input that the C program/daemon is running continuously:

```
cfile="/home/workspace/printprocess/print"
pid_file=/path/to/pid_file.txt
if [ "$1" = start ] ; then
  # Start C program into the background
  $cfile &
  # Store PID in a file.
  echo "$!" > $pid_file
  # Wait for C program to exit (or get killed)
  wait
  # Remove PID file
  rm $pid_file
  # or use echo "something" to put something to the $pid_file.
fi
```